# How to pass multiple commands via pssh and multiple xterms

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, xterm, parallel-ssh

I'm attempting to open multiple xterms and run a command as an SAP user via sudo using `pssh`. So far, I'm able to run PSSH to a file of servers with no check for keys, open every xterm in the servers in the file list, and sudo to the SAP (ADM) user, but it won't do anything else afterwards.

I've tried many combinations and I'm not sure if my options for the `pssh` nor the xterm options are set correctly. Here is what I have now.

```
pssh -i -h ectsrv -A -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no "export DISPLAY=IP address:0.0;  xterm -hold -e "sudo /path/sap_sudo.sh" "
```

I've tried many combinations: with and without single and double quotes:

```
xterm -e sudo "cmd1;cmd2;ls;bash"
xterm -e sudo "cmd1 && cmd2"
xterm -e sudo "cmd1;cmd2; ksh"
xterm -e sudo "-tt" "cmd1;cmd2;ls;bash"
```

I'm completely stuck where `SIDADM>` is shown in new windows, but it won't run any commands.

Comment: I'm just seeing this while searching for something else. I'm not sure if this will help but I do similiar things using tmux. With a hotkey, I open multiple panes with a different sever in each one. Then with another hotkey, whatever I type in one pane shows on all the panes. So in essence I can enter any command and what I'm typing shows on all terminals simultaneously. If you don't know the tmux tool yo should look into it. It's a more advanced version of screen IMHO. Hope this helps.

Comment: @IbrahimSalimOmari notes "I do similar things using tmux. With a hotkey, I open multiple panes with a different sever in each one. Then with another hotkey, whatever I type in one pane shows on all the panes. So in essence I can enter any command and what I'm typing shows on all terminals simultaneously. If you don't know the tmux tool yo should look into it. It's a more advanced version of screen IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the xterm piece however if trying to run multiple commands I had luck doing the following:

```
pssh -i -h ectsrv -A -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no "sudo cmd1; cmd2"
```